# What is the difference between "in my opinion" and "to my taste"?

Tags: grammar, differences, expressions

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to+my+taste

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/for%20my%20taste

I don't see in those links any mention of opinion, it's not even a synonym.

Are those two expression totally different and what is the difference? What about to use "to my taste" metaphorically for the same meaning as "in my opinion"?

Comment: An opinion is usually formed by knowledge or experience, while taste can be fleeting.

Comment: You can certainly use "to my taste" metaphorically, but it is a statement about your *preferences*, while "in my opinion" is more a statement of your *beliefs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, one's taste and one's opinion can be two different things.

It may suit your taste to have cigars after dinner, for example, but your opinion might be that cigars should not be smoked at all for health reasons or consideration for others, etc. And yet, being human, you might lapse from that behavior even though your opinion about it might remain the same.

Comment: So I can't say, "cats are dicks, to my taste" right ?

Comment: @user88212 right. The two phrases mean completely different things.

Comment: @user88212 I'd be careful about anything relating to the taste of cats' dicks if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Taste here is synonymous with personal preference, and that can be driven solely by emotions/feelings and not necessarily have anything to do with logic or principle.
Opinion, on the other hand, is usually a perspective on some topic supported by some logic or principle/ideology.